# Simple SQL query on small tables takes too long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have a query that takes much too long time to execute. It is simple and tables are small. The simplified query (but still slow) is:

```
SELECT D.ID, C.Name, T.Name AS TownName
  FROM Documents D, Companies C, Towns T
  WHERE C.ID = D.Company AND T.ID = C.Town
  ORDER BY C.Name
```

Primary keys and foreign keys between tables are properly set. Also, column `Companies.Name` is indexed.

I tried using JOINs, restarting SQL Server, rebuilding indices etc. but it still needs about 40 seconds to execute on my computer with SSD. Number of records in tables `Documents` and `Companies` is only 18K (currently, they are 1:1) and only about 20 records in table `Towns`.

On the other side, the following query returns completely the same records, but it takes practically no time to execute:

```
SELECT D.ID, C.Name, (SELECT Name FROM Towns WHERE ID = C.Town) AS TownName
  FROM Documents D, Companies C
  WHERE C.ID = D.Company
  ORDER BY C.Name
```

In my opinion, the first query should be even faster, but I am obviously wrong. Does anybody have a clue what's happening here? It seems that indices are ignored when sorting by column in a table which is a master of one and detail of another one.

Comment: Why are you still using the old ANSI-89 style joins? You should use the newer join syntax, it has been around for well over 20 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: what happens if you go Town > Company > Documents.. using joins

Comment: If you want real help you need to provide the actual ddl including index definitions along with row counts for the tables. An actual execution plan would help too.

Comment: Have you looked at the plan?  It should tell you where the resources are being spent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why your subquery query is running faster but I would try something else to see if I could eliminate the subquery.

I usually go from least to greatest when i'm not using where conditions.. So my query would look like

```
Select  t.Name TownName,
        c.Name,
        d.Id
From    Towns t
        Join Companies c ON t.Id = c.Town
        Join Documents d ON c.Id = d.Company
Order By c.Name
```

Then I'd make sure that Companies has an Index on Town, and that Documents has and index on Company.. 18k records might take a little while to display in the output window but the query should be pretty quick

Comment: The query was equaly slow. Also, adding index on Town did not help, but adding index on Company in Documents table worked! I (wrongly) assumed that the foreign key would be enough. Still, it's a mistery to me why the other query runs fine, although it's diferent table. Also, removing the Cities table from queries will make queries instant.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you use join statements?

```
SELECT D.ID, C.Name, T.Name AS TownName
FROM Documents D
inner join Companies C on C.
inner join Towns T on T.ID = C.Town
ORDER BY C.Name
```

also, try with and without the order

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried INNER JOINS like this one and it is equaly slow:

SELECT D.ID, C.Name, T.Name AS TownName
  FROM Companies C
  INNER JOIN Documents D ON C.ID = D.Company
  INNER JOIN Towns T ON T.ID = C.Town
  ORDER BY C.Name

I also tried to use `Documents` table in `WHERE`, as you suggested, but nothing changed.

Without `ORDER` it's instant.